# Understanding the ResNet paper

Tags: deep-learning, mathematics

I am having trouble understanding the mathematical meanings behind the notations in the ResNet [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf):

I believe that the function we are trying to optimize is the residual which is denoted as $\mathcal{F}(x) + x$, with $\mathcal{F}(x)$ is the output of the 2 or 3 convolution layers and x is the original input before the convolutions.

My question is: what is $\mathcal{H}(x)$ that is mentioned a number of times in the paper so that $\mathcal{F}(x) = \mathcal{H}(x) - x$ ?

Not quite sure what is meant by "desired underlying mapping, $\mathcal{H}(x)$" and "Underlying mapping to be fit by few stacked layers"

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share a link to the exact paper?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{H}(x)$ is the function you want to approximate with your Neural Network.

Typically, you train a model $\mathcal{H}_\theta(x)$ that directly tries to learn that function by minimizing some loss $\mathcal{L}(h(x), \mathcal{H_\theta}(x)), h(x) \sim \mathcal{H(x)}$, but in this paper the authors show that it is easier to optimize the residual $\mathcal{F}(x) := \mathcal{H}(x) - x$, i.e every layer learns only a small part of $\mathcal{H}(x)$, so that the composition of all layers provide a better approximation.